# Angular js : How to create directive for form control

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

In angular js I want to directive to create directives to manage my dom element.
I want to create custom for text, select radio and checkbox.

I have Json with list of question those I want to ask to user. 
this json has question, its type (**text, select radio and checkbox**) and answer options.

I want to pass que data to directive and use those data while creating html element.

Here I am stuck how to pass que to directive and and use inside directive.

Comment: This isn't  a code writing or tutorial service. You need to be a lot more specific than *"how to..."*. Show that you tried that isn't working as expected

Comment: added directive code.